# How to delete a pointer assigned to a base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, delete-operator

I have a base class `A`  and a derived class `B`.

```
class A
{
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    void func1();
    virtual void func2();
};

class B : public A
{
    B();
    ~B();
    void func2();
};

int main()
{
    A* lBaseobj = new A ( );

    lBaseobj->func1( );
    lBaseobj = new B( );
    lBaseobj->func2( );

    delete lBaseobj;
return;
}
```

My question is: does `delete lBaseobj` frees the memory allocated to the `lBaseobj` object by `new A( )` as well or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use smart pointers, memory will not be leaked:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> lBaseobj(new A());
// or: auto lBaseobj = std::make_unique<A>();
lBaseobj->func1();
lBaseobj.reset(new B()); // will delete resources allocated by new A()
lBaseobj->func2();
return 1; // destructor of lBaseobj will delete resources allocated by new B()
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does "delete lBaseobj " free the memory allocated to the lBaseobj
>   object by new A( ) also or not.

**NO** and **YES**, from your example.

Below you leak memory, as `A` is not deleted:

```
...
lBaseobj->func1( );  // where is delete lBaseObj; ??
lBaseobj = new B( );
...
```

Below is ok, as the `A::~A()` is virtual:

```
...
lBaseobj->func2( );
delete lBaseobj;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the initial object is not destroyed:

```
A* lBaseobj = new A ( );
lBaseobj->func1( );
delete lBaseobj; // call delete here
lBaseobj = new B( );
```

A rule of thumb you should obey: for every `new` there should be a `delete`, for every `new[]` there should be a `delete[]`.

In your code, you have 2 `new`'s, but only 1 `delete`.